# Shopify Theme Development - What other paginate styles are there? paginate | default_pagination

Tags: pagination, themes, shopify

I am trying to find documentation highlighting the other options that come with the {{ paginate | default_pagination }} pagination tag.

The default styles {{ paginate | default_pagination }} create:

[image]

Can anyone let me know what the pagination type would be to get this output:

[image]

EDIT: Thanks for confirming there is no other built in styles other than default. Here is how I achieved this appearance:

```css
.pagination {
 margin: 20px;
 color: #0E0530;
}
.pagination,
.pagination-inner {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
.pagination-page {
 margin: 0 10px;
 color: #0E0530;
}
.pagination-previous,
.pagination-next {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
 transition: all 0.7s;
}
 .pagination-previous:hover,
 .pagination-next:hover {
  border-color: #E20437;
 }
```

```html
<!--

{% comment %} With shopify code {% endcomment %}

{% if paginate.pages > 1 %}
  <div class="pagination">

   <div class="pagination-inner">

    {% if paginate.previous.is_link %}
    <a class="pagination-previous" href="{{ paginate.previous.url }}"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/chevvy-red-left.png?1420" class="paginate-prev-icon" alt="prev"></a>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="pagination-page">Page {{ paginate.current_page }} of {{ paginate.pages }}</div>
    
    {% if paginate.next.is_link %}
     <a class="pagination-next" href="{{ paginate.next.url }}"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/chevvy-red-right.png?1420" class="paginate-next-icon" alt="prev"></a>
    {% endif %}

   </div>
   
  </div>
{% endif %}

-->

<!-- without shopify shortcodes -->
 <div class="pagination">

  <div class="pagination-inner">

   <a class="pagination-previous" href="{{ paginate.previous.url }}"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/chevvy-red-left.png?1420" class="paginate-prev-icon" alt="prev"></a>

   <div class="pagination-page">Page 1 of 2</div>
   
   <a class="pagination-next" href="{{ paginate.next.url }}"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0043/0886/0977/files/chevvy-red-right.png?1420" class="paginate-next-icon" alt="prev"></a>

  </div>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: I suggest you check these first  https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/paginate

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I understand you can grab the components of the pagination and build your own style, but are there other option other than default pagination?

Answer (score 0):

No there are no other built in pagination styles but with the paginatio object you can create this pagination easily. To do so you can have a look at below code from [Shopify Debut Theme](https://themes.shopify.com/themes/debut/styles/default)

```
<ul class="list--inline pagination">
  {% unless paginate.previous.is_link %}
    <li aria-hidden="true">
      <button class="btn btn--tertiary btn--narrow" disabled>
        {% include 'icon-arrow-left' %}
        <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'general.pagination.previous' | t }}</span>
      </button>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ paginate.previous.url }}" class="btn btn--tertiary btn--narrow">
        {% include 'icon-arrow-left' %}
        <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'general.pagination.previous' | t }}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endunless %}
  <li class="pagination__text">
    {{ 'general.pagination.current_page' | t: current: paginate.current_page, total: paginate.pages }}
  </li>
  {% unless paginate.next.is_link %}
    <li aria-hidden="true">
      <button class="btn btn--tertiary btn--narrow" disabled>
        {% include 'icon-arrow-right' %}
        <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'general.pagination.next' | t }}</span>
      </button>
    </li>
  {% else %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ paginate.next.url }}" class="btn btn--tertiary btn--narrow">
        {% include 'icon-arrow-right' %}
        <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'general.pagination.next' | t }}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endunless %}
</ul>
```

It outputs the same pagination as you need and then you can style it accordingly.

[Paginate Object](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/paginate)